# Select Filled Cell in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, contenteditable

I am trying to make editable if the cell is filled. If it is not filled yet, it will not be editable.

I am using contenteditable but I can not select the td's all is fit my condition. When I try to write if, when one td is filled all td's are chosen. I tried to write if inside of foreach but I guess I can not do this because jquery selection doesnt return any array etc.

Do you have any suggestion ?

```
var edit3 = $('#table_mresults tbody tr').find(':nth-child(3)');
var edit4 = $('#table_mresults tbody tr').find(':nth-child(4)');

if(edit3 != "" && edit4 != ""){


    edit3.attr('contenteditable','true');
    edit4.attr('contenteditable','true');
}
```

---

```
var edit3 = $('#table tbody tr').find(':nth-child(3)');
var edit4 = $('#table tbody tr').find(':nth-child(4)');

edit3.forEach(e3 => {
    if(e3 != "") e3.attr('contenteditable','true');
});

edit4.forEach(e4 => {
    if(e4 != "") e4.attr('contenteditable','true');
});
```

**edit:** Solution Suggestion

Maybe I should try to give editable class for the filled rows and then selected with this class name ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the element inner text NOT the element itself as in:

```js
if(edit3.text().trim() != "" && edit4.text().trim() != ""){


    edit3.attr('contenteditable','true');
    edit4.attr('contenteditable','true');
}
```

Comment: No, there is not any problem checking element itself. I can make them editable ! The problem is when any of them is filled, all rows' 3rd tds are also selected when I write edit3.attr('contenteditable','true')